# Can AutoMapper map to a different destination property when one matches source?

Tags: c#, automapper

For example, suppose I have the following...

```
public class TheSource
{
    public string WrittenDate { get; set; }
}

public class TheDestination
{
    public string CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime WrittenDate { get; set;}
}
```

and I have the mapping as such...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TheSource, TheDestination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CreateDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WrittenDate));
```

Question: Is the Automapper trying to map the `TheSource.WrittenDate` to `TheDestination.WrittenDate` instead of `TheDestination.CreateDate` as I specified in the `.ForMember`?

-- I ask this because I am getting an AutoMapper DateTime exception from the CreateMap line above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the Automapper trying to map the TheSource.WrittenDate to TheDestination.WrittenDate instead of TheDestination.CreateDate as I specified in the .ForMember?

Not instead of `TheDestination.CreateDate`.

- Automapper will map `src.WrittenDate` to `dest.CreateDate` because you specified that explicitly.
- And it will map `src.WrittenDate` to `dest.WrittenDate` because by convention, if you don't specify otherwise, properties with the same name will be mapped to each other when you create the map.

To override this behavior, you can explcitly tell Automapper to ignore `dest.WrittenDate` like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TheSource, TheDestination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CreateDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WrittenDate))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.WrittenDate, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you.  I understand now.  Although I was specifying that src.WrittenDate go to dest.CreateDate, AutoMapper wanted to ALSO map src.WrittenDate to dest.WrittenDate.  Makes sense.